# Jenkins - Docker integration - Use Jenkins to build Docker images and push to the registry

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, docker

I am currently working on integrating Docker with Jenkins and I am currently trying to figure out the following pipeline:

Whenever a Dockerfile is updated in GIT, trigger a Jenkins Job to do the following

1. Build the Docker image
2. List item
3. Test, Verify the Docker image
4. Version the image - Prod, testing etc.
5. Push the image to the registry
6. If the image is not built, have a proper mechanism to get the logs

From my research, I found that we have 2 different plugins for Jenkins for Docker integration - Build step plugin and Docker build publish plugin. As far as I could see, I could not see any plugins or workflow to test the image before pushing it to the repository. Since we are doing this from the scratch, I would like to know the best tried and tested workflow.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We applied the same mindset like "git flow" to the creation of docker images. In our solution, there was no need for testing the image itself. We solved that splitting up the Build in to a "Source-Build" producing artifacts and a downstream job e.g. "Runtime-Build" only packaging the artifacts into the runtime and pushing into the registry. At this point the whole stack is delivered to a "Release-Stage" for automatic testing.

Answer (score 0):

To test the image there's a tool called Anchore.
Then, if you want to integrate other types of tests before building the Docker image, you can integrate for example Sonarqube with Jenkins and do a static analysis of the source code. Full example at: https://pillsfromtheweb.blogspot.com/2020/05/integrate-sonarqube-static-analysis-in.html